# How to pass file contents as argument to custom github action?

Tags: shell, github-actions

I have written a custom Github action, which connects to a running server and executes MYSQL statements which are passed as argument. Example usage looks something like this:

```
jobs:
  setup:
    name: MySQL Database Setup
    runs-on: [ self-hosted]

    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Execute mysql commands
        uses: myaction@main # all of this is self hosted in our case
        env: 
          MYSQL_USERNAME: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_ADRESS: some.mysql.server.domain.com
          MYSQL_PORT: 10207
        with:
          args: |
            "SHOW DATABASES;"
```

This works nicely, but the next step would be to pass a `.sql` file from the checked out repo to the custom action. Can I pass this directly somehow, or do I need to insert an extra step to my job to read the file contents and store it in a variable? Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add input argument to your action, so that you can use it with your action.
As a part of your action read the file and pass it where you need it.

Example:

- input definition

  - [npalm/action-docs-action/action.yml#L14](https://github.com/npalm/action-docs-action/blob/781459da1d6771a5ba7c34c50dec512a4b834306/action.yml#L14)
- get

  - [npalm/action-docs-action/src/main.ts#L8](https://github.com/npalm/action-docs-action/blob/781459da1d6771a5ba7c34c50dec512a4b834306/src/main.ts#L8)
- usage

  ```
  - uses: npalm/action-docs-action
    with:
      actionFile: custom_file.yml
  ```

Comment: Will this copy the complete file into my action instance?

Comment: No, the file will be where it's checked out. If I remember correctly the action gets executed in the context of current workspace.

Comment: OK, while I haven't tested this I am sure it will work. However in my particular case I went with adding an extra job step and reading the file contents into that, since I need to pass only the contents (my action expects a string). I will mark the answer nonetheless, since I found it helpful.

Comment: You can extend your action to read the file first and then pass to your tool.
Otherwise you can use simple bash `cat file.jql` and set output: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter.
Remember multiline strings need special treatment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings